# How to distinguish whether the image is coming from gallery or camera in android?

Tags: android, gallery, android-camera-intent

I am making an app in which i can pick an image from gallery or i can take image from camera and i am moving to next activity with the selected image.There I want to distinguish whether the image is coming from gallery or camera.I am not getting any idea how to do it.I am providing my code.Please help me how to do this.

My first activity is

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;



  public class LauncherActivity extends Activity 
   {
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
 private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
 ImageButton camera;
 ImageButton gallery;
 ImageView gallery_image;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
 {
 super.onCreate(paramBundle);
 setContentView(R.layout.launcher);
 gallery = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.select_photo);
 camera = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.take_photo);





   gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
            Intent gallery_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery_intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
     }
    });

     camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
    }
});

  }
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



  if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)     {



      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

      String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };



      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
              filePathColumn, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();

      int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
      String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
      cursor.close();
      Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("path", picturePath);
      startActivity(intent); 

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {  

      Bitmap photo_from_camera = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      photo_from_camera.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
      byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
      Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
      startActivity(intent);


    }  
  }
  }
```

and my second activity is

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity 
   {
   Bitmap scaled;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
  super.onCreate(paramBundle);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   if(//condition to The image coming from gallery)
   {
   Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
   String picturePath=extras.getString("path");
  scaled=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
  //the things i have to do with bitmap that i know
   }    
  if(//Condition to the image coming from camera)
  {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("image");
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
  scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
  //the things i have to do with bitmap that i know
  }
  }
   }
```

Here I am not getting the code to write the conditions in the if statement.please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
startActivityForResult(gallery_intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

regarding to your request code you can differentiate image is coming from gallery or camera

```
 boolean gallery;

     if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
        //then image from camera

gallery=true;
    galleryIntent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("path", picturePath);  
         intent.putExtra("isfrom", gallery); 
    startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE){
    galleryIntent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("path", picturePath);  
         intent.putExtra("isfrom", gallery); 
    startActivity(intent);
        //then image from gallery
        }
```

in second activity you can get boolean from intent.if it is true image from gallery

Comment: it is used to distinguish in the same activity.I am moving to second activity with the selected image.In the second activity,I want to distinguish.This wont work there.

Comment: you can make a flag in first activity onActivityResult(),and use it in second activity

Comment: can u tell me in detail plz.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("path", picturePath);  
     intent.putExtra("isfrom", gallery); startActivity(intent);

Comment: @rajahsekar he won't understand because he doesn't know how to program (atleast in android). You answer is good, let it be.

Comment: there is a string for gallery image called path and for camera image called image.I think this is enough.no need of flag if i am not wrong.I do not know how to distinguish with these two strings in the second activity in the if statement.

Comment: Thanks yaar.It was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

launcher.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/select_photo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gallery"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/take_photo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camera"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

activity_main
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>

LauncherActivity.java
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 2;
    Button camera;
    Button gallery;
    ImageView imageView;
    private String imgPath;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.launcher);
        gallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_photo);
        camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

    }

    public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
                Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("path", getAbsolutePath(data.getData()));
                intent.putExtra("from", "Gallery");
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getImagePath()));
                Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("path", getImagePath());
                intent.putExtra("from", "Camera");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
            final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            final String imageOrderBy = null;
            Uri tempUri = getUri();
            Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(tempUri, imageColumns,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "="+id, null, imageOrderBy);
            if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }

    }

    private Uri getUri() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Toast.makeText(this,getIntent().getStringExtra("from"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra("path")));

    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}

Note : please not forget this permission in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```