# Capturing and storing photo not working - Android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm using these codes to capture and store an image on a button click.

```
takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        destination = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                preferences.getSelectedItem().getItemNo() + "_" 
                + preferences.getSelectedItem().getChasisNo() + "_up");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(destination));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        FileInputStream in;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(destination);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 10;
            imgPath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Image saved", "Image saved at " + imgPath);
        upItem.setUpPhotoURL(String.valueOf(imgPath));
        isPhotoAttached = true;
    }
}
```

But when I capture the photo and try to confirm it, app does nothing. Cancelling and retaking options work perfectly but confirming the taken image doesn't do anything. Can anyone point me where the problem lies here?

Comment: Look at my ans here it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606330/how-to-distinguish-whether-the-image-is-coming-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/23606878#23606878

Comment: The problem is, the resultCode is not working when I'm pressing the confirm button. I tried Log.d("Test", String.valueOf(resultCode)); But a log is only created when I press the cancel button (Test : 0) and nothing when I'm trying to press the confirm button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not working because the name of the image is too big. When I changed this

```
destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                preferences.getSelectedItem().getItemNo() + "_" 
                + preferences.getSelectedItem().getChasisNo() + "_up");
```

to this

```
destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                preferences.getSelectedItem().getChasisNo() + ".jpg");
```

I'm not sure if there's such a thing as the image name being too big, but this change is working for me

Answer (score 0):

added this permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
    int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

Toast.makeText(this, capturedImageFilePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: I tried just editing the Manifest but no effect at all. Then I tried copying your onActivityResult but it says the method managedQuery() is deprecated

Comment: No, not working. It says there's a NullPointerException at the "int col..." line

Comment: on which line please write that line

Comment: The problem is, the resultCode is not working when I'm pressing the confirm button.
I tried Log.d("Test", String.valueOf(resultCode));
But a log is only created when I press the cancel button (Test : 0) and nothing when I'm trying to press the confirm button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath = destination.getAbsolutePath();

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
                getBitmap(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    default:

        break;
    }

}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String mCurrentPhotoPath) {

    /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
    /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

    /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap oribitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,
            bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 3;

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    return oribitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,
            bmOptions);

}
```

This permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: The problem is, the resultCode is never RESULT_OK. I tried logging the resultCode but it never logs anything when I'm pressing the confirm button. It logs 0 when I pressed cancel

Comment: Change this line :                                                  case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE: { instead of case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {