# I am unable to transfer the image taken from camera from one activity to another activity in android?

Tags: android, file, camera

I know how to transfer the image taken from camera from one activity to another activity.But here the image is not displayed in the second activity.I know this is very easy thing.But i was stuck here.Please tell me where i did the mistake.I am transferring the image via byte array and i am getting null pointer exception over the bitmap which has been transferred.

my first activity is

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

 public class Working extends Activity{
ImageView first,second;
Button set;
Bitmap bitmap,scaled;
RelativeLayout relative;
String path;
File file;

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.working);
 first=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 set=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);                 
 set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
 });

 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                        f = temp;

                        break;

                    }

                }

                try {

                    Bitmap bitmap;

                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize=2;

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),

                            bitmapOptions); 



                    first.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



                     path = android.os.Environment .getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator+ "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";

                    f.delete();

                    OutputStream outFile = null;

                    file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");

                    try {

                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outFile);

                        outFile.flush();

                        outFile.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }               
                 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Working.this, Temp.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
      }
       }

           }
```

my second activity is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class Temp extends Activity{
   ImageView iv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.temp);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("image");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Look at my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606330/how-to-distinguish-whether-the-image-is-coming-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/23606878#23606878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.I am writing my two activities here.

My first activity is

```
  import java.io.File;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Environment;
  import android.provider.MediaStore;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

  public class Working extends Activity{
ImageView first,second;
Button set;
Bitmap bitmap,scaled;
RelativeLayout relative;
String path;
File file;

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.working);
 first=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 set=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);                 
  set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

      File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
  });

   }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                        f = temp;

                        break;

                    }

                }



                    Bitmap bitmap;

                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize=2;

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),

                            bitmapOptions); 



                    first.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Working.this, Temp.class);
                    i.putExtra("imagePath" ,f.getAbsolutePath() ); 
                    startActivity(i);
      }
  }
 }
 }
```

my second activity is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class Temp extends Activity{
 ImageView iv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.temp);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize=6;    
    String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,bitmapOptions);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 }
 }
```

my first activity xml file and second activity xml file are same.the xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/relative" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>"

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be passing the byte array in intent as it can cause problems if the image size is large. Instead why don't you just pass the path in the intent and read from the path in the next activity.

Comment: i tried that way.I did not get any null pointer exception.But the image was not displayed in second activity.

Comment: can u please tell me your way of passing path

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer
In first Activity

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivty.this, secondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then in your second Activity
Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: here the image should be taken from camera.I know your code works well for  the bitmap which is formed from resources

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the alternative for it to pass the direct path of sd card where your image was captured.

Pass the Byte array from one activity to other is not good practice.

i think you should decode the path of sd card and after try it. it should be work.

1.) first pass the path in second activity in string.

2.) get that string with the key and apply this logic in your second activity.

```
 File file = new File("your sdcard path");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just Edit your code just try hope this helps you

**Working.java**

```
public class Working extends Activity {
    ImageView first, second;
    Button set;
    Bitmap bitmap, scaled;
    RelativeLayout relative;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
    private String imgPath = "";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.working);
        first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    }

    public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Working.this, Temp.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", getImagePath());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Temp.java**

```
public class Temp extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code.The image is not displayed in second activity.Only blank screen is there.Can u suggest other way please.

Comment: Is application crashes?

Comment: which version of Android in your device?

Comment: i have 3 devices.two with gingerbird and one with ice cream sandwitch

Answer (score 0):

Replace intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)); this line with 
intent.putExtra("image", f.getAbsolutePath());

and get that path in your Second Activity Using 
getintent().getextras.getString("image");

Thats it... i hope that will help you...

Comment: The image is not displayed in the second activity

Comment: there are you can get image path only decode it from path then you can set it to imageview

Comment: String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);