# how to pass the bitmap from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera

I have two activity , the first activity (camera Activity) contain two button one to open the camera , and the second activity display form contain the image view  I need to pass the bitmap that capture from camera in another FORM activity 
,the camera open and taken the image and this image put on imageview on another Activity 
but my code is taken image and return to first activity does not display on second activity ?

the camera code

```
public class camera extends Activity {
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);


    //register
   Button camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.s_camera);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            open();
        }
    });

    Button call = (Button)findViewById(R.id.s_call);
    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:0555064740");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



}

public void open(){


   Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), formActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bp);

    }


    }
```

the formActivity

```
public class formActivity  extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;
Bitmap photo;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
    getData();



}
private void getData(){

    Bitmap bitImage=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitImage);

}
```

any one can help me ???

Comment: Pass a `URI` instead of `Bitmap`

Comment: Do not pass bitmap from one activity to another. Instead, save the image in a file and send the file path to next activity.

Comment: Spring Breaker answer is good, you can also use onActivityResult() to get the bitmap in the first activity, tell me if you want more explanation.

Comment: you miss startActivity(intent) in the first activity

Comment: Look at my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606330/how-to-distinguish-whether-the-image-is-coming-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/23606878#23606878

Answer (score 1):

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable`, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

you miss `startActivity(intent)` in the first activity as commented by [blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt). Update it in your `onActivityResult()`.

reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2459624/1665507

You can find a working example in below link,

http://androidmaterial.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-pass-bitmap-between-activities.html

**EDIT:**

As commented by others, sending big images as `Parcelable` is not recommended. You can use the below method also,

Pass `Bitamp` as Extended Data

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 //Compress it before sending it to minimize the size and quality of bitmap.
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
        byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();
    
        Intent anotherIntent = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
        anotherIntent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
        startActivity(anotherIntent);
        finish();
```

Retrieve `Bitmap` in Other Activity

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("image")) 
   {
    ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);        
    previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
```

reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12908133/1665507

Also there is a other way. Though you are taking picture from Camera or Gallery, you can always get the exact `URI` path of the image and can pass that path to the other activity.
Sending big images requires a lot of memory so as per your need, choose the best way.

Comment: he is actually doing it

Comment: You can only pass very small bitmaps (like icons) in an Intent's Parcelable. For  a camera use case it's better to pass the Uri of the image file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), formActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bp);

    }
 }
```

in the snippet you miss `startActivity(intent)`. On the other hand, in `formActivity.class`, before `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitImage);` you have to initialize `imageView` otherwise your app will crash. As mentioned in the comment box, it would be better to provide the `URI` of the picture instead of passing the whole bitmap to the `formActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is quite old, here is a solution that works better without any compression or quality loss and also don't have to create temporary bitmap file

1. Create a BitmapHelper class

   ```
   public class BitmapHelper {
   private Bitmap bitmap = null;
   private static final BitmapHelper instance = new BitmapHelper();

   public BitmapHelper(){

   }

   public static BitmapHelper getInstance(){
       return instance;
   }

   public Bitmap getBitmap(){
       return bitmap;
   }

   public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
       this.bitmap = bitmap;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Now get or set your bitmap from any activity like this

   ```
   //to set the bitmap
   BitmapHelper.getInstance().setBitmap(saveBitmap);
   //to get the bitmap
   anyImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapHelper.getInstance().getBitmap());
   ```