# how to send a image to next screen on button click

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, buttonclick

i created a grid view app in which i am swiping images on a swipe_view screen.

now i want to send image that is showing on swipe_screen to a new screen.

what i want is that image is current on swipe_view screen i want to send that image to new screen on button click.

**see my code.**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    // Some items to add to the GRID
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] 
            { 
            "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears",
            "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary",
            "Micheal Buble" 
            };
    static final int[] ICONS = new int[] 
            { 
            R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb 
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // get the photo size and spacing
        mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
        mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

        // initialize image adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

        photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

        //start sent image to full screen             

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        photoGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  View v,
                    int position,   long id ) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SwipeActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);

            }            
        });
        //end sent image to full screen

        // set image adapter to the GridView
        photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
        photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                        imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                    }
                }
            }
        });     
    }

    // ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        // set numcols
        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            mNumColumns = numColumns;
        }

        public int getNumColumns() {
            return mNumColumns;
        }

        // set photo item height
        public void setItemHeight(int height) {
            if (height == mItemHeight) {
                return;
            }
            mItemHeight = height;
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null)
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

            ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            // Check the height matches our calculated column width
            if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
            title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

            return view;
        }
    }

}

//swipe image class
```

**SwipeActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SwipeActivity extends Activity 
{           

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);        

 // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

    //send image to full_view.xml screen on button click
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xoom);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // how to sent current showing image to new screen

        }

    });
    //

    //send data to grid view on button click
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v2) 
        {
//          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            // passing array index            
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    });
  }  

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
  {
      int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;    

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
      Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
//      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
//          R.dimen.padding_large);
//      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
      imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
}


//swipe image layout
```

**swipe_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Grid" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/xoom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Zoom"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Wallpaper" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**below is the class and xml where i want to get image from swipe_view screen**

**Full_Zoom.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Full_Zoom extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_view);               



}
}
```

**full_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_full"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**_________________________________________________________________________________**

this is what i tried but after trying this what happens is it get position from selected grid image not from swipe_view screen. i want to get and send image from swipe_view screen not from selected grid image.

because i want to zoom current swiping image in new screen.

but because of this code

```
// get intent data
            Intent i3 = getIntent();

            // Selected image id
            int position = i3.getExtras().getInt("id");
            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Full_Zoom.class);
            // passing array index
            i2.putExtra(null, R.id.view_pager);
            startActivity(i2);
```

it get image from selected grid view but i want to get image from current showing swiping image.

**SwipeActivity.java**

```
//send image to full_view.xml screen on button click
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xoom);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // get intent data
            Intent i3 = getIntent();

            // Selected image id
            int position = i3.getExtras().getInt("id");
            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Full_Zoom.class);
            // passing array index
            i2.putExtra(null, R.id.view_pager);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    });
    //
```

**Full_Zoom.java(new screen class)**

```
public class Full_Zoom extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_view);               

     // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        PinchZoom img = new PinchZoom(this);
        img.setImageResource(MainActivity.ICONS[R.id.view_pager]);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
        setContentView(img);

}
}
```

Comment: Are you storing images anywhere?

Comment: See this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606330/how-to-distinguish-whether-the-image-is-coming-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/23606878#23606878,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send image inside onclick:**

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this,YourClassName.class);
    i.putExtra("imageID", icons[position]);
    startActivity(i);
```

**get this on new activity :**

```
Bundle bd = getIntent().getExtras();
int imageRes = bd.getInt("imageID");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
image.setImageResource(imageRes);
```

Comment: if image size is large then first  convert Image into Byte Array and then pass into Intent and in next activity get byte array from Bundle and Convert into Image(Bitmap) and set into ImageView.

Comment: How about storing the file in SD card and retrieving it in next activity?

Comment: Please asked a new question on s.o, I will be happy to help you. Because it is not impossible to give the answer in comment.

Comment: It's ok, I don't need the answer. I was just asking you.

Comment: wait i am uploading my code, you try it and u will understand what is wrong

Comment: this is the like of my project http://www.mediafire.com/download/a1xikkudn73ae4f/Copy_of_TD_GridView.rar